# Shorten Salesforce formular

Tags: salesforce

I've build a formular that is too long for Salesforce to process.

Any advice on how to shorten it? It needs to be shortened by roughly 150 characters.

Kindly,
Rasmus

```html
IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=11.5, 12,
                IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=10.5, 11,
                    IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=9.5, 10,
                        IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=8.5, 9,
                            IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=7.5, 8,
                                IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=6.5, 7,
                                    IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=5.5, 6,
                                        IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=4.5, 5,
                                            IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=3.5, 4,
                                                IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=2.5, 3,
                                                    IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=1.5, 2,
                                                       IF(VALUE(Text(Snit_gym__c))>=0.5, 1,
                                                            0.0
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                 )
             )
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could devote another custom field to storing Snit_gym__c as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your if else statements are taking away the actual else conditional logic. You're basically performing 10 if statements. Reduce it by flipping the conditions around, start high and work to a lower value.